# Убрать значение в периоде

Tags: java

Как можно убрать значение в периоде в строке? т.е. например вот это".(0)", естественно количество нулей может быть разное

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения. 
Например:

```
String s="2.00001";
s.replaceAll("\\.0+$|(\\.\\d*[1-9])(0+)$","");//"2.00001"

s="2.00000";
s.replaceAll("\\.0+$|(\\.\\d*[1-9])(0+)$","");//"2"

s="2.(000)";
s.replaceAll("(\\.\\(0+\\))","");//"2"
```